# What is wrong with my program reversing strings in C?

Tags: c, string, pointers, reverse

I want to create a function to reverse a string in C. I found a couple pre-made on the internet but I wish to create mine. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


char* inverseCarac(char* chaine){
    if(chaine==0||*chaine==0) return NULL;  

    int j, i;
    int taille=strlen(chaine); 
    char* inverse=malloc(taille*sizeof(char));

    for(j=taille-1, i=0; j>0; j--, i++){
        *(inverse+i)=*(chaine-j);
    }

    return inverse;

}

int main(void){
    char* test="bonjour";
    char* inv=inverseCarac(test);
    printf("%s", inv);
    return 0;
}
```

I can't figure out why I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: First thing - you do not `malloc` enough space for the null terminator.

Comment: I don't see why using two indices. I think it should be `i` only.

Comment: `malloc(taille*sizeof(char));` --> `malloc(taille+1);` and add a `nul` terminator.

Comment: Thanks, I tried but the problem is it doesn't print anything.

Comment: @SNus you may be copying the null terminator into inverse[0] which wouldnt print anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several errors in your code, the most significant being the offset from `chaine` in the wrong direction. Also, lack of space for a string terminator, and `j` ending prematurely.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* inverseCarac(char* chaine){
    if(chaine==0||*chaine==0) return NULL;  

    int j, i;
    int taille=strlen(chaine); 
    char* inverse=malloc(taille+1);             // add 1 for terminator

    for(j=taille-1, i=0; j>=0; j--, i++){       // change j>0 to j >= 0
        *(inverse+i)=*(chaine+j);               // change -j to +j
    }
    inverse[taille] = '\0';                     // write terminator
    return inverse;
}

int main(void){
    char* test="bonjour";
    char* inv=inverseCarac(test);
    printf("%s\n", inv);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output

```
ruojnob
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH, that was it. You're great